# Copy next three month value from Current Month move to another sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have sample Data from Jan to dec 2023. From Current month(July) I want to Next three Month Value copy to new Workbook .

For Example for current Month June ,it will take Next three Month . if its July it  will take August,sep,Oct.

Sales workbook --> New workbook.

Sales Workbook.xlsx

```
Month           Value       Desc
01-01-2023       300        001
01-02-2023       500        001
01-03-2023       200        001
01-04-2023       400        001
01-05-2023       500        001
01-06-2023       500        001
01-07-2023       700        001
01-08-2023       800        001
01-09-2023       200        001
01-10-2023       100        001
01-11-2023       300        001
01-12-2023       600        001
```

New workbook

```
01-07-2023       700        001
01-08-2023       800        001
01-09-2023       200        001
```

```vb
    Sub CopyNextThreeMonths()
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
        Dim currentDate As Date
        Dim nextThreeMonths As Range
        Dim nextMonth As Date
        
        ' Set the source sheet ( "Sales Workbook")
        Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales Workbook")
        
        ' Set the destination sheet ("New workbook")
        Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New workbook")
        
        ' Set the current date
        currentDate = Date
        
        ' Set the range for the next three months
        Set nextThreeMonths = destinationSheet.Range("A1:C100") ' Adjust the range as per your requirement
        
        ' Loop through each cell in the range and copy values from the corresponding cells in the source sheet
        For Each cell In nextThreeMonths
            nextMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, currentDate)
            If Month(nextMonth) = Month(cell.Value) And Year(nextMonth) = Year(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Value = sourceSheet.Range(cell.Address).Value
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try showing what you tried by your own. At least some research, not working code etc. It is good to prove that you do not only ask... Then, you must better describe the real need. For instance, what about the November current month? **How would you like the code to behave**?

Comment: @FaneDuru  I have attached my code what i have tired

Comment: OK, except the case that you did not answer my question (**what about the November current month?**)... I will try helping after clarifying it. Will there be other records for the next year? If  not, how the code to proceed?

Comment: Are there already data on Sheet "New workbook" or is it empty? If it is empty then `nextThreeMonths` will return empty cells ...

Comment: @lke yes  I have created new worksheet  with name of New workbook..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try using the next code:

```
Sub MoveFollowingThreeMonthsData()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, wbN As Workbook, curD As Date, copyRng As Range, mtch
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  curD = Date

  mtch = Application.match(CLng(DateSerial(Year(curD), Month(curD), 1)), ws.Range("A2:A" & lastR), True) 'find the row of the current month
  If IsNumeric(mtch) Then 'if a match exists:
    Set copyRng = ws.Range("A" & mtch + 2, "C" & mtch + 4) 'set the range to be copied
    Set wbN = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)                    'create a new workbook, with a single sheet
    copyRng.Copy wbN.Sheets(1).Range("A1")                      'copy the necessary range in the single sheet of the newly created workbook (in A1)
  End If
End Sub
```

It assumes that the range to be processed exists in columns A:C, starting with the first row. And there will also be data after December, current year when the code will work for October - December months...

If not cell format copying is necessary, the code can be easily adapted to copy an array of the range.

The next version is your adapted code, using the sheets you use:

```
Sub CopyNextThreeMonths()
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, destinationSheet As Worksheet
        Dim currentDate As Date, curMonth As Date, lastR As Long, copyRng As Range, mtch
        
        ' Set the source sheet ( "Sales Workbook")
        Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales Workbook")
        lastR = sourceSheet.Range("A" & sourceSheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on column A:A
        
        ' Set the destination sheet ("New workbook")
        Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New workbook")
        
        ' Set the current date
        currentDate = Date
        
        mtch = Application.match(CLng(DateSerial(Year(currentDate), Month(currentDate), 1)), sourceSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastR), True) 'find the row of the current month
        If IsNumeric(mtch) Then 'if a match exists:
            Set copyRng = sourceSheet.Range("A" & mtch + 1, "C" & mtch + 3) 'set the range to be copied
            copyRng.Copy destinationSheet.Range("A1")                                       'copy the necessary range in destinationSheet (A1)
            destinationSheet.Activate 'activating the destination sheet
        Else
            MsgBox "No any current month has been found..."
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Thennarasu Doesn't the above code do what you try accomplishing? Do you need it to handle in a different way current month numbers greater than 9? If so, please explain how these cases to be halndled?

Comment: date Range from 01-01-2022 to 01-12-2023  .. its fixed date . Need show three month data from current Month . i am going try with above code

Comment: @Thennarasu Yes, but if current date will have a month greater than 9, it will return three lines after it. Meaning two or one row containing data and the rest up to three being empty.

Comment: I am going to only three months data from Current month .. its fixed only three Months not more then 3 months

Comment: Did you test the above code?

Comment: getting Subscript out of Range Error .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254282/discussion-between-thennarasu-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Thennarasu "Subscript out of Range Error" does not make too much sense if **you do not say on which code line the above error is raised**. Then, **do you have the data in columns A:C, starting from the first row, as my answer stated**?

Comment: @Thennarasu All the code works on the active sheet. You can easily change `Set ws = ActiveSheet` with `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales Workbook")`. Then, you wrote: "Sales workbook --> New workbook". If your so named "New workbook" is a sheet, you do not need a real new workbook you should use the respective sheet when pasting...

Comment: Thank you .. i will try with Active sheet method

Comment: @Thennarasu It looks that your VBA skills are not so high... Please, test the last version I posted (I edited my answer), which uses the sheets you have in your code and send some feedback... Before that, refresh the page (this one).

Comment: @Thennarasu Couldn't you test it?

Comment: Code Is run with out Error but paste is not  working New Workbook sheet. i am checking on that

Comment: @Thennarasu What do you mean by New Workbook sheet? Do you use "New Workbook" as the sheet name. It does not paste **anything** only if your Date are not in column A:A or this range **is  not formatted As Date**. Do you have AnyDesk installed? If so, do you accept a connection to let me see what's happening in your installation?

Comment: @Thennarasu Please, use the adapted code. It now send a message if the current date could not be found... What about AnyDesk?

Comment: sorry i am using office system without Admin approval not able to use any desk app

Comment: @Thennarasu I do  not have a problem with this aspect. Only tried to solve the problem as rapidly as possible. But, did you test the updated code? Does it send any message? Does it work as it should? What's happening? In order to be helped, you should answer all clarification questions, not only part of them...

Comment: code return without error but values are not copying to new workbook sheet.

Comment: @Thennarasu I was not talking about an error... I adapted the last code version to send a **message** if a match exists between current `Date` and the A:A range, where the data range must exist. Now, firstly, do you use the adapted code having a `MsgBox` before `End If`? if so, try running the code line by line, consecutively press `F8` and see what's happening. Moving the cursor over any variable (in this case, over `mtch`) it will display the variable value. What does it display when try running the code in this way?

Comment: Now values are passing to new sheet but passing the all value . i want to move only three month based  current month

Comment: @Thennarasu This cannot happen, I think... Did you try running the code line by line, as I suggested above? You maybe check the return in a wrong sheet... Please, try the adapted code. I modified it now **to select the destination sheet**... Do you know what a `BreakPoint` is and how to place it in the code?

Comment: @Thennarasu Are you sure that **the destination sheet is empty before running the code**? If not, you have to check the **first three rows**! Do you want it returning **starting from A1**, or **after the last existing record**?